# How can I return Scaffold as WatchShape builder result?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is a code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wear/wear.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Body Temperature Tracker',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<double> _kayit = [36.5, 36.7, 37.2, 36.9, 37.4];

  void _addRecord(double value) {
    setState(() {
      _kayit.add(value);
    });
  }

  void _removeRecord(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _kayit.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  double _calculateAverage() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (double record in _kayit) {
      sum += record;
    }
    return sum / _kayit.length;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WatchShape(
      builder: (context, shape) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Body Temperature Tracker'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Your average body temperature is:',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                Text(
                  '${_calculateAverage().toStringAsFixed(1)} °C',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  'Your latest records are:',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _kayit.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('${_kayit[index]} °C'),
                        trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: () => _removeRecord(index),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              double value = 36 + 2 * Math.random();
              _addRecord(value);
            },
            tooltip: 'Add a new record',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The error I got:

```json
[{
    "resource": "/C:/src/flutter_project/flutter_application_9/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": {
        "value": "argument_type_not_assignable",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/diagnostics/argument_type_not_assignable",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The argument type 'Scaffold Function(BuildContext, WearShape)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, WearShape, Widget?)'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 52,
    "startColumn": 16,
    "endLineNumber": 100,
    "endColumn": 8
}]
```

The argument type `Scaffold Function(BuildContext, WearShape)` can't be assigned to the parameter type `Widget Function(BuildContext, WearShape, Widget?)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the builder you defined is a function that takes two parameters, but the builder that is expected should take three.

If you look at the example at https://pub.dev/packages/wear the builder has a third parameter named child.

Try changing

```
 builder: (context, shape) {
```

To

```
 builder: (context, shape, child) {
```

Answer (score 0):

While I never worked with `wear` myself, I noticed example on https://morioh.com/a/c55262e5fcf1/create-a-wear-os-app-using-flutter that includes [`InheritedShape`](https://pub.dev/documentation/wear/latest/wear/InheritedShape-class.html) to provide shape for child:

```dart
class WatchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => WatchShape(
        builder: (context, shape) => InheritedShape(
              shape: shape,
              child: AmbientMode(
                builder: (context, mode) =>
                    mode == Mode.active ? StartScreen() : AmbientWatchFace(),
              ),
            ),
      );
}
```

In your example I could look like:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WatchShape(
      builder: (context, shape) => InheritedShape(
          shape: shape,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Body Temperature Tracker'),
            ),
            //...
```

but you would have to test that.